# Carousel: return to the first slide after arrive to the end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an images carousel with prev and next arrows; i need to return to the first image when i arrive at the end of slides (to the last slide) and i click to the prev arrow.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="slide one"></div>
        <div class="slide two"></div>
        <div class="slide three"></div>
        <div class="slide four"></div>
        <div class="slide five"></div>
        <div class="slide six"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="prev"></button>
<button class="next"></button>
```

```
.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.slide {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 1px;
  float: left;
}

.next, 
.prev {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  top: 25px;
}

.next {
 right: 0;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}
```

```
var carousel = $('.carousel');

$('.next').on('click', function() {
    carousel.animate({
        left: '-=25vw'
    }, 500);
    
});

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
    carousel.animate({
        left: '+=25vw'
    }, 500);

});
```

This is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jweau4v/61/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your js file as follows.

```
var carousel = $('.carousel');
var currentSlide = 0;

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  if(currentSlide == $('.slide').length) {
    carousel.animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 500);
    currentSlide = 0
  } else {
    carousel.animate({
        left: '-=25vw'
    }, 500);
    currentSlide += 1
  }
});

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  if(currentSlide == 0) {
    return 
  } else {
    carousel.animate({
        left: '+=25vw'
    }, 500);
    currentSlide -= 1
  }
});
```

I added a if block to see if it's at the end of the list when showing the next image